# Ignore public folder files (robots.txt and sitemap.xml) for specific domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku

I am running a Rails app on Heroku with a custom domain. Let's call my Heroku app `myapp.herokuapp.com` and the custom domain `www.myapp.com`. I have accidentally gotten myapp.herokuapp.com indexed (some 700-3000 indexed pages) by Google causing duplicate content between the two.

I recently discovered this and put a 301 in a before_filter in applications controller like this:

```
  def forward_from_heroku
    redirect_to "http://www.myapp.com#{request.path}", :status => 301  if request.host.include?('herokuapp')      
  end
```

This successfully redirects (almost) all traffic from myapp.herokuapp.com to www.myapp.com I have also requested an adress change to myapp.com in Google Webmaster Tools.

This works fine, except for files in the public folder (obviously). The problem is that it still access robots.txt and sitemap.xml, which in turn points to an external sitemap (at AWS). I could see how Google-bot interprets this as there is still content to be browsed (although everything is 301'd) on myapp.herokuapp.com.

What I would like to do is to add code to the app so that if Google access the website through myapp.herokuapp.com they get one sitemap.xml/robots.txt and another if it is accessed through www.myapp.com

How can I code this in my config.rb or elsewhere? Basically, I need to bypass the public folder for myapp.herokuapp.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did, it's not elegant but it works. I removed sitemap.xml and robots.txt from public folder and put them in the config folder. Then:

```
routes.rb

  get '/robots.txt' => 'home#robots'
  get '/sitemap.xml' => 'home#sitemaps'


  def robots 
    unless request.host.eql?('myapp.herokuapp.com')
      robots = File.read(Rails.root + "config/robots.txt")
      render :text => robots, :layout => false, :content_type => "text/plain"    
    end
  end

  def sitemaps
    unless request.host.eql?('myapp.herokuapp.com')
      sitemaps = File.read(Rails.root + "config/sitemap.xml")
      render :text => sitemaps, :layout => false, :content_type => "text/xml"    
    end    
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can constrain routes based on domain:

```
scope constraints: {host: /^regex-matching-your-domain/} do
```

then just return a 404 for robots.txt and sitemap.xml within that scope:

```
scope constraints: {host: /heroku.com$/} do
  get '/robots.txt' => Proc.new { |env|
    [404, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['Not Found']]
  }
end
```

**also:** you may consider using canonical urls. it may be a more effective solution for SEO, i'm not sure. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: I have tried this and many different versions of your solution but I can still reach the robots.txt through myapp.herokuapp.com (and yes, I used 'herokuapp.com' and not 'heroku.com' as in your example, which I assume was a typo). Does this really bypass the public folder?

Comment: yeah.. no, it doesn't. /public taken priority over routes, so this won't work. Since it's deployed on Heroku, Rails is serving the static assets, so you could insert something in the middleware before the built-in static file server that would do this like: `config.middleware.insert_before 'ActionDispatch::Static', YourMiddlewareForRobots`

Comment: @Christoffer did you look into the canonical fix? that might be a simpler solution at this point.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have done a canonical as well now. I tried a solution that works but is not very elegant. I do a get reference in routes.rb to home#robots in which I ignore robots.txt for everything but my original domain. It works but is quite "ugly".

Comment: I have implemented rel=canonical as well. I will have to wait and see what kind of effect that will give.